# Adding Triggers in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to add a trigger in my database in phpmyadmin to rollback an insertion into the table if a particular attribute is greater than 100.

Here is my code that I wrote in the window for define in the "Add Trigger" window:

BEGIN
ROLLBACK IF NEW.max_allowed > 100
END;

I am getting this error:
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NEW.max_allowed > 100 END' at line 2

Can someone please suggest what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ROLLBACK` can't be used together with `IF` in the same statement.
[Check the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html).

I suggest this code for your trigger:

```
BEGIN
 IF NEW.max_allowed > 100 THEN
  ROLLBACK;
 END IF;
END;
```